# SQL FOR XML list of nested rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, for-xml

I have this super long SQL query, now what this query does is the following, creates the first level which is the Job_No....next in the second level gets all the 'BaselineStart' however this separates each BaselineStart with baseOrSchedStartList, what I am looking to do is have 1 baseOrSchedStartList for each Job_No and have each 'string' under baseOrSchedStartList. I hope this makes sense. Here is my query:

```
SELECT [Job_No] as '@Key',
(
        SELECT ISNULL(UserDate1,ScheduleTasks.BaselineStart) AS 'string' 

        FROM ScheduleTasks INNER JOIN Schedule ON ScheduleTasks.ScheduleID = Schedule.ScheduleID INNER JOIN V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES ON V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER = Schedule.Job_No WHERE Job_No IN (SELECT JOB_NUMBER
                        FROM V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES
                        WHERE AREA_DESC = 'Orchard Park'
                        AND (DATE_TO_END IS NOT NULL AND DATE_TO_END >= GETDATE())) AND
               (
                        LibraryTaskID <> 203
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 204
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 210
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 211
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 214
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 215
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 218
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 219
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 224
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 227
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 230
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 231
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 232
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 233
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 234
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 235
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 236
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 237        
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 238
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 239
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 240
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 242
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 243
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 295
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 299
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 303
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 304
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 305
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 313
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 314
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 321
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 333

               )

            ORDER BY DATE_TO_END, SortOrder
            FOR XML PATH('baseOrSchedStartList'), Type
)
FROM ScheduleTasks INNER JOIN Schedule ON ScheduleTasks.ScheduleID = Schedule.ScheduleID INNER JOIN V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES ON V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.JOB_NUMBER = Schedule.Job_No WHERE Job_No IN (SELECT JOB_NUMBER
                        FROM V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES
                        WHERE AREA_DESC = 'Orchard Park'
                        AND (DATE_TO_END IS NOT NULL AND DATE_TO_END >= GETDATE())) AND
               (
                        LibraryTaskID <> 203
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 204
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 210
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 211
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 214
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 215
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 218
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 219
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 224
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 227
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 230
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 231
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 232
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 233
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 234
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 235
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 236
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 237        
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 238
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 239
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 240
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 242
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 243
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 295
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 299
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 303
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 304
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 305
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 313
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 314
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 321
                        AND LibraryTaskID <> 333

               )
               GROUP BY [Job_No]
               FOR XML PATH('Job_No'), ROOT('Root')
```

This query returns this data:

```
<Root>
  <Job_No Key="ORC0023">
    <baseOrSchedStartList>
      <string>2015-09-11T08:00:00</string>
    </baseOrSchedStartList>
    <baseOrSchedStartList>
      <string>2015-08-10T16:00:00</string>
    </baseOrSchedStartList>
    <baseOrSchedStartList>
      <string>2015-08-11T16:00:00</string>
    </baseOrSchedStartList>
  </Job_No>
</Root>
```

what I am looking for is the following:

```
<Root>
  <Job_No Key="ORC0023">
    <baseOrSchedStartList>
      <string>2015-09-11T08:00:00</string>
      <string>2015-08-10T16:00:00</string>
      <string>2015-08-11T16:00:00</string>
    </baseOrSchedStartList>
  </Job_No>
</Root>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you change `FOR XML PATH('baseOrSchedStartList'), Type` to `FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('baseOrSchedStartList'), Type` in your subquery that should do it.

Comment: I just found your follow-up question and extended my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE According to your [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36587999/5089204)

If you just take away the `@` from the `AS [@Key]` you'll get this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE([Key] VARCHAR(10),DateValue DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('ORC0023','2015-09-11T08:00:00')
                       ,('ORC0023','2015-08-10T16:00:00')
                       ,('ORC0023','2015-08-11T16:00:00')

DECLARE @UniqueKey VARCHAR(10)='ORC0023';
SELECT @UniqueKey AS [Key]
      ,(
        SELECT DateValue AS [string]
        FROM @tbl AS tbl 
        WHERE tbl.[Key]=@UniqueKey
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
       ) AS baseOrSchedStartList
FOR XML PATH('Job_No'),ROOT('Root')

/*
<Root>
  <Job_No>
    <Key>ORC0023</Key>
    <baseOrSchedStartList>
      <string>2015-09-11T08:00:00</string>
      <string>2015-08-10T16:00:00</string>
      <string>2015-08-11T16:00:00</string>
    </baseOrSchedStartList>
  </Job_No>
</Root>
*/
```

#### UPDATE2 For your actual query this means (probably)

Try to change the `as '@Key'` to `as Key`

and the

```
        ORDER BY DATE_TO_END, SortOrder
        FOR XML PATH('baseOrSchedStartList'), Type
)
```

to

```
        ORDER BY DATE_TO_END, SortOrder
        FOR XML PATH(''), Type
) AS baseOrSchedStartList
```

Another alternative was - as pointed out by BateTech in a comment - to put your "baseOrSchedStart" as `,ROOT('baseOrSchedStart')` behind the `FOR XML PATH('')` and let the paranthesis unnamed...

#### previous

Without your table's structures and test data it is difficult to fully understand your query (which isn't that *super long* actually :-)   )

Therefore I prepared a simplified structure example and hope, that you can understand the approach and transfer this to your actual data

Just try the following:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE([Key] VARCHAR(10),DateValue DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('ORC0023','2015-09-11T08:00:00')
                       ,('ORC0023','2015-08-10T16:00:00')
                       ,('ORC0023','2015-08-11T16:00:00')

DECLARE @UniqueKey VARCHAR(10)='ORC0023';

--This is structurally what you've got
SELECT @UniqueKey AS [@Key]
      ,(
        SELECT DateValue AS [string]
        FROM @tbl AS tbl 
        WHERE tbl.[Key]=@UniqueKey
        FOR XML PATH('baseOrSchedStartList'),TYPE
       )
FOR XML PATH('Job_No'),ROOT('Root')

/*
<Root>
  <Job_No Key="ORC0023">
    <baseOrSchedStartList>
      <string>2015-09-11T08:00:00</string>
    </baseOrSchedStartList>
    <baseOrSchedStartList>
      <string>2015-08-10T16:00:00</string>
    </baseOrSchedStartList>
    <baseOrSchedStartList>
      <string>2015-08-11T16:00:00</string>
    </baseOrSchedStartList>
  </Job_No>
</Root>
*/
```

Now try it like this

```
SELECT @UniqueKey AS [@Key]
      ,(
        SELECT DateValue AS [*]
        FROM @tbl AS tbl 
        WHERE tbl.[Key]=@UniqueKey
        FOR XML PATH('string'),TYPE
       ) AS baseOrSchedStartList
FOR XML PATH('Job_No'),ROOT('Root')

/*
<Root>
  <Job_No Key="ORC0023">
    <baseOrSchedStartList>
      <string>2015-09-11T08:00:00</string>
      <string>2015-08-10T16:00:00</string>
      <string>2015-08-11T16:00:00</string>
    </baseOrSchedStartList>
  </Job_No>
</Root>
*/
```

Btw: This is the same as this:

```
SELECT @UniqueKey AS [@Key]
      ,(
        SELECT DateValue AS [string]
        FROM @tbl AS tbl 
        WHERE tbl.[Key]=@UniqueKey
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
       ) AS baseOrSchedStartList
FOR XML PATH('Job_No'),ROOT('Root')
```