# SQL Server Stored Procedure XML can't get node right

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have this query here:

```
SELECT [Job_No] as '@Key',
(
)
FOR XML PATH('Job_No'), ROOT('Root')
```

and it returns like so:

```
<Root>
  <Job_No Key="ORC0023">
  </Job_No>
</Root>
```

How do I get it like so:

```
<Root>
      <Key>ORC0023</Key>
    </Root>
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the syntax used

Comment: Hi I extended my answer to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36584180/5089204) to cover this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT [Job_No] as 'Key'  FROM Jobs
FOR XML PATH(''), root ('Root');
```

[working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/7849)